Configure Tailwind to use 16px fontSize when document fontSize is set to 14px
I have a kind of unusual situation. A number of large Vue applications have been developed standalone using TailwindCSS in HTML documents with the defaultt 16px font size.
They are now being mounted inside of an existing .NET web app. Unfortunately, the document font size for the .NET web app is set to 14px; so all the rem based calculations used by tailwind calculate smaller sizes/padding/heights/margins than desired.
IOW we want to keep the Tailwind CSS class names (and consequently the sizes/padding/heights/margins) in the mounted Vue applications when they are in a parent document that has a non-standard font size.
I'm hoping there is a general solution that doesn't involve redefining all the effected properties in the tailwind config.

It looks like this is a known issue in Tailwind. The maintainers recommend modifying the tailwind.config.js to have the desired values.
There also appear to be postfix plugins, tailwind plugins, and other scripts that can convert rems to px or scale rems to rems:
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/1611
This tool sounds like it might solve the issue for me:
https://github.com/CedericPrivat/tailwindcss-base-font-size
